# Will a Norwegian skogkatt (forest cat) feel good in Sydney?

Tags: cats, acclimation, weather

I'd like to have a *skogkatt* but am concerned that it would feel uncomfortably hot in Australia, with all of its thick fur.

So the question is: will a weggie be able to adapt to hot and humid climate?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you planning that this cat will spend most of it's time indoors or outdoors? If indoors will there be Air conditioning? If outdoors what kind of housing (or free roaming)?

Comment: I think legally cats must be kept indoors in Australia. I may vary by state

Comment: Indoors would be OK :) I was thinking about taking the cat for hiking / camping trips, like this: http://www.adventurecats.org/cat-tales/norway-cat-skis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cat is an indoor cat and having air conditioning it will be ok, but if the cat is outdoors it will be too hot even in the shade; even here in Norway the summer heat is at the limit for the forest cat.

Hiking and camping will often be problematic for any cat, I have often taken walks in the forest with my cats and they do overheat quite fast even if the temperature is comfortable for us; after what is a short walk for us, like a kilometer or two, the cats are totally exhausted.

And remember: no two cats are alike, so the cat might really hate going for hikes in unknown areas, and as you probably know cats can be really really stubborn if they refuse to do something.

There are breeds of cats that are more active than others, so it might be better to look into them to find a hiking friend for you.

And remember: any cat will eventually get exhausted and need you to carry it and the Norwegian forest cat is large, so it might be problematic for you to carry it for a long distance.

More information about Norwegian forest cat could be found [in this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_Forest_cat) on Wikipedia.

[image]

My adopted feral cat he is probably a forest cat mix.

Comment: Tusen takk for rådet Trond! (jeg kommer til Norge i september på en campingtur i Tromsø og lærer Norsk nå :)


Translation as it's probably illegal to use non-English language on the SE: Thanks for the advice Trond (I'm coming to Norway in September on a hiking trip to Tromsø  so I'm learning the language now)

Comment: @Alexander  it is a beautiful part of norway i hope you get nice weather so you will get a memory for life,it is intense if the weather is on your side.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not get a skogkatt in Australia.

As trond hansen points out, those cats are not adapted to warm climates. Worse, they are adapted to **cold climates**. So unless you are able to provide an air-conditioned environment for your cat all the time, I would strongly recommend against it.

Second, it's very chancy you get the temperament you want in the kitten / cat you adopt. You might get the biggest couch potato cat in Australian history. Or a shy bugger that only comes out when you watch tv.

Third, you will need to import the cat (probably) into Australia. Quite a bit of work and cost. For a cat badly adapted for a warm climate.

Lastly, cat's are a [feral nightmare for birds in Australia](https://www.google.nl/search?q=australia+cats&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=-MbEWt1uhNnwB96Jp-gJ). Please don't add to that...

And I'll assume that there are cat rescue centres in Sydney. May I suggest you visit one of those? Maybe they have a cat with the personality type you are looking for! (and for a proper cat, you don't chose the cat, the cat selects her / his butler ;)

Comment: Thanks Flummox, unfortunately I can't upvote your answer due to low rep :)
Of course I agree about feral cats, I won't let it loose! I remember our garden variety little predators decimating birds and once even bringing a live squirrel when I was a kid (and nobobdy cared about free-roaming cats) :)

Thanks for the comment that weggies are accustomed to a cold climate, I had been thking so as well but wanted a second opinion.